# C++ / C - odd code

Tags: c++, fastcgi

I am looking at some sample code and cant work out what the following lines are doing:

```
   fcgi_streambuf cin_fcgi_streambuf(request.in);
   fcgi_streambuf cout_fcgi_streambuf(request.out);
   fcgi_streambuf cerr_fcgi_streambuf(request.err);
```

I dont come from a c background so the syntax looks a bit odd - each line is calling a function in initialising a new object but i would expect at least an assignment in there.  For example:

```
    fcgi_streambuf = cin_fcgi_streambuf(request.in);
    fcgi_streambuf = cout_fcgi_streambuf(request.out);
    fcgi_streambuf = cerr_fcgi_streambuf(request.err);
```

The full example code can be found here: http://chriswu.me/blog/writing-hello-world-in-fcgi-with-c-plus-plus/

Comment: You're probably confused because they are not functions, but constructors, which are similar but not exactly the same thing. The same same syntax is present here: `int x (0);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, each line is defining a variable.

```
   fcgi_streambuf cin_fcgi_streambuf( request.in );
// ^-type-------^ ^-name-----------^  ^-params-^
```

Where the parameter is passed to the constructor of class `fcgi_streambuf`. **While not 100% accurate**, it might help to think of it this way:

```
fcgi_streambuf cin_fcgi_streambuf = fcgi_streambuf( request.in );
```

Answer (score 3):

Those lines are declaring three variables of type `fcgi_streambuf` and calling the constructor for that type.